# Accesing shm structure using pointer

Tags: c, memory, pointers, structure, shared

I have a c structure like this :

```
struc str{
  int values[10];
}str
```

In a posix so like fedora i copied this structure to a part of shared memory (`shm_open`, `ftruncate`, `mmap` and `memcpy`) and I got a pointer to structure from shm. Now how do I change a value in the values array by using this pointer (*ptr).

Imagine i want to do str->values[5] = 10; how to I do that using the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the pointer:

```
struct str *p = ptr;
p->values[5] = 10;
```